# How to change background color of combobox

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I change the background color of a Combo Box in C++ using the Windows API?

Comment: I used the search string "MSDN c++ combobox background color".  Possible duplicate [How to set background color of combobox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a92cb62b-9a92-4e32-afb9-a9366ba0e1e1/how-to-set-background-color-of-edit-control-and-combobox-control?forum=vclanguage).  The internet is an amazing place, search first.

Comment: Another possibility:  [SetBkColor function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Another selection from my previous search.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please edit your post with a simple function of what you have tried.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: `SetBkColor` by itself is of little help. It sets the background color for text rendering into a device context. You'd need to create an owner-drawn control, and handle all rendering functions, to make use of it. That's almost like answering the question *"How do I create an aeroplane?" with *"Use welding."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can create a brush in heap, for example using

```
static HBRUSH hbrush;
...
hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
```

Then in Window or Dialog procedure, handle `WM_CTL***` messages and return the brush handle, for example

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
case WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX:
{
    HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 255)); //change text color
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT); //change text-background color, or set it to transparent
    return (INT_PTR)hbrush;
}
```

This works for ComboBox too. If you want to handle different controls individually, you can check `lParam` against the control's handle.

For a ComboBox it's a little more complicated. You have to get the handle to ComboBox's EditBox and ListBox. You can do that using `GetComboBoxInfo`

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
case WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX:
{
    HWND hTest = (HWND)lParam;
    COMBOBOXINFO ci = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
    GetComboBoxInfo(hComboBox, &ci);

    if (
        hTest == ci.hwndItem ||
        hTest == ci.hwndList
        )
    {
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        return (INT_PTR)hbrush;
    }
}
```